# Requsting help on app update using flutter

Tags: flutter, in-app-update, app-update

I am new to flutter, I am here to seek help in how to implement app update in flutter. Like How it is implemented or What are the ways to implement upates in an app using flutter.

I have tried with upgrader package but it is not working properly, i.e I am not getting the alert message

Answer (score 0):

You can use

1. firebase_remote_config - https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_remote_config (both android and ios)
2. in_app_update - https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_update (android only)

I use both!